# Wordpress Posts Grid Images leaving gray space on resolution above 1280

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been struggling with this post grid which I really like and want to use. But I dislike the gray part that appears besides te picture. Even the play button on a video post gets moved to the gray part instead of staying on the picture.

I am working with the newspaper theme using big grid 7, I have been trying to change the way the box works withing chrome's inspect but I can't figure it out.

Here is the website [www.breakline.nl](http://www.breakline.nl/); the post grid is just above the footer (for now). You can clearly see what I mean when you zoom in or out while looking at the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to your css file

```
img.entry-thumb.td-animation-stack-type0-2 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above is right, but also you may add the below to complete remove the grey color from behind.

```
.td-big-grid-post .td-module-thumb{background:none!important;}
```

Generally go to the Appearance > Editor  find the style.css file and at the bottom line around 33036 make a markup something like `/*my own CSS*/` and add the below lines.

```
img.entry-thumb.td-animation-stack-type0-2 {
width:100%;}
.td-big-grid-post .td-module-thumb{background:none!important;}
```

Press Update file, and you are ready.

Credits go to @Relisora